# Alert throttling framework in C#

Tags: c#, logging, alerts

Is there a framework in C# that manages alert throttling? I currently use log4net and [this caching appender](http://handmadecode.com/2011/07/25/24/) along with some of my own code but think there may be something out there already.

I want to receive alerts whenever they happen and then get reminded of them periodically but not during certain hours. I also use Twilio for text alerts which I would like the framework to handle if it exists.

I've heard of people using Rx and nServiceBus to do this type of thing but haven't found had any concrete examples and haven't found the time to learn these frameworks yet.

Comment: use SNARL and it's freeware too - http://fullphat.net/

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look